# implicitly constructing a singleton

Tags: haskell, singleton, dependent-type

I'm trying to implicitly construct a singleton and then pass it into a function witch computes on singletons. I want to help GHC infer the type and I haven't figured out a way to do it.

```hs
singletons [d| data Mood = Angry
                         | Sad
                         | Neutral
                         | Happy
                         | Excited deriving (Read, Eq, Ord, Show) |]

singletons [d| data Intensity = None
                              | Low
                              | Medium
                              | High
                              | Extreme deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Enum) |]


singletons [d| newtype MoodReport = MR (Mood, Intensity) deriving Show |]


moodReportToSing :: forall (a :: Mood) (b :: Intensity). (SingI a, SingI b) => MoodReport -> SMoodReport ('MR '(a,b))
moodReportToSing (MR (a,b)) = sing :: Sing ('MR '(a, b))


addSingMoodReports :: forall a a' (b :: Intensity) (c :: Intensity). SMoodReport ('MR '(a, b)) -> SMoodReport ('MR '(a, c)) -> SMoodReport ('MR '(a, b <> c))
addSingMoodReports (SMR (STuple2 a b)) (SMR (STuple2 a' c)) = SMR $ STuple2 a (b %<> c)


unsafeAddMoodReports :: MoodReport -> MoodReport -> MoodReport
unsafeAddMoodReports (MR (a, c)) (MR (b, d)) = MR (a, d <> c)
```

the `moodReportToSing` is still explicit and needs TypeApplications in order to to be used. The problem with SomeSing is that it loses type data (or if it doesn't, I don't know how to use that data) and only has kind data in it and I want to pass these to the `addSingMoodReports` function. Is there anyway to make these implicitly, help GHC infer their type or bypass type-erasure?

Comment: If you could do that Haskell would have true dependent types. Until then, types don't depend on values, so if you don't want to lose a value when promoting it, it should be at the type level to begin with (or the promotion should be done at the earliest possible point).

Comment: I am extremely confused what you're asking. Do you want `tryAddMoodReports :: MoodReport -> MoodReport -> Maybe MoodReport; tryAddMoodReports (FromSing l@(SMR (STuple a b)) (FromSing r@(SMR (STuple a' c)) = do { Refl <- testEquality a a'; return $ FromSing $ addSingMoodReports l r }`?? The closest thing to `moodReportToSing` that can exist is something like `data SomeMoodReport = forall a b. SomeMR (Sing (MR '(a, b))); fromMoodReport :: MoodReport -> SomeMoodReport; fromMoodReport (FromSing l@(SMR (STuple a b))) = SomeMR l`. (Assuming all that compiles...)

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Li-yaoXia , you are right. I tried to think about ways to promote them as soon as possible but I couldn't find a way to satisfy what I'm trying to do. Wish you and professor Weirch the best on your research.

Comment: @HTNW your function works great and I'm super happy for providing it but I'm trying to find a type-safe function to use it in order to provide a Monoid instnace for the `MoodReport`  type. Unfortunately the `tryAddMoodReports` function you provided, as good as it is, still returns a `Maybe MoodReprt`. Therefore I can't  write a Monoid Instance with it unless I add a runtime error to a wrapper function that wraps your tryAddMoodReports.

Comment: If MoodReports can only be combined when they match in Mood then MoodReport isn't a Monoid, full stop.